# What format do I write my date into Core Data for an attribute with date type?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to populate the sqlite database used by my core date model with the proper type of date for each entry (one for each day in the month). What format should I store the date in the sqlite database so that my app can display it correctly or at least receive a format it understands which I can tweak using date formatter?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saving dates, you read and write `NSDate` objects. They do not have a date format-- they just store an absolute time offset since the reference date.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just have to go with JSON ;)